# how to extract xml element values with string find in lua

Tags: xml, string, lua, match, element

I need to extract Username, Password element values from soap header within soap envelop using lua.

Sample request -

```
...
<soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=“http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd” soapenv:mustUnderstand=“1”>
<wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password wsse:Type=“http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText”>testpassword</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header>
...
```

using following is not giving the right result (can not use xml parsers), any better way to Pattern it ?

```
local username = string.match(soapload, "^.+Username>(.+)</wsse:Username>.+$")
local password = string.match(soapload, "^.+PasswordText\">(.+)</wsse:Password>.+$")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example uses the "right double quotation mark" (`PasswordText”>`) code \u201D , so you didn't get anything. And they don't need to be escaped, this is unnecessary.

```
local soapload = [[
<soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=“http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd” soapenv:mustUnderstand=“1”>
<wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password wsse:Type=“http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText”>testpassword</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header>
]]

local username = string.match(soapload, "<wsse:Username>(.-)</wsse:Username>")
local password = string.match(soapload, "PasswordText”>(.-)</wsse:Password>")

print(username)
print(password)
```

Comment: for some reason i got both nil, will check again.

Comment: may be try this pattern  `"PasswordText.->(.-)</wsse:Password>"`

Comment: Thanks Mike. i had some strange behavior while sending this via soap ui, with postman worked fine.